# Generating strings based on a given grammar sometimes results in non stop printing

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void PareY();
void PareA();
void PareB();
void PareE();
static list<string> s;

void showlist(list<string> g)
{
    list<string>::iterator it;
    for (it = g.begin(); it != g.end(); ++it)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
    cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  cout << "<E>::=(<Y>)" << endl;
  cout << "<Y>::=<A><B>" << endl;
  cout << "<A>::=ν|<Ε>" << endl;
  cout << "<Β>::=-<Υ>|+<Υ>|ε" << endl;
  PareE();
  cout << "---------------" << endl;
  showlist(s);
  return 0;
}

void PareE(){
  cout << "E -> (Y)" << endl;
  s.push_back("(");
  PareY();
  s.push_back(")");
}

void PareY(){
  cout << "Y -> AB" << endl;
  PareA();
  PareB();
}

void PareA(){
  if((rand() % 2 ) == 0){
    cout << "A -> ν" << endl;
    s.push_back("ν");
  }else{
    cout << "A -> E" << endl;
    PareE();
  }
}

void PareB(){
  if((rand() % 3) == 0){
    cout << "B -> -Y" << endl;
    s.push_back("-");
    PareY();
  }
  else if((rand() % 3) == 1){
    cout << "B -> +Y" << endl;
    s.push_back("+");
    PareY();
  }else{
    cout << "B -> ε" << endl;
  }
}
```

I have to create strings based on the grammar seen in the couts in the main function.

1. When i run tests, it sometimes prints stuff nonstop (it only stops if i hit the stop) why is that?
2. I have to show the steps as well e.x E -> (Y) -> (AB) -> (νB) -> (ν-Y) -> (ν-(ΑΒ)) and so on instead of what i've done (i'm just showing the production rule) and i don't know how to do that. I'm using a list there just for the outcome but should i use a list as well for the production? I don't know how else to do it.

```
<E>::=(<Y>)
<Y>::=<A><B>
<A>::=ν|<Ε>
<Β>::=-<Υ>|+<Υ>|ε
E -> (Y)
Y -> AB
A -> ν
B -> ε
---------------
 ( ν )
```

That's an example. It should be something like E -> (Y) -> (AB) -> (νΒ) -> (ν). The only thing i can think of is having a list storing the current string..

Comment: I looked at this for a few minutes. For #1 it could be correct in that some sequences could be very long.

Comment: For which sequence of random numbers does in not behave as expected? What would be expected? See, random numbers are notorically bad when used in a [mcve]. Either they are irrelevant (then they can be removed) or they are significant (then they shouldn't be random). In any case, learn how to step through code with a debugger. You seem to have an IDE, just locate a video tutorial for it. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah i thought of that too but we also have to make sure the program stops at some point so i'm kinda lost here.

Comment: I think you are just not waiting long enough.

Comment: In `void PareB(){` you probably should pick the random number 1 time at the start of the function instead of in each `if ()`

Comment: @drescherjm so create a local variable and assign the random number there?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean.

Comment: Still happens but of course the code looks cleaner. My main problem now is the 2) part

Comment: With this grammar, you are very likely to expand infinitely. Each `Y` has 5/6 probability to split in two branches, and only 1/6 probability to terminate. And to stop generating, you need every single branch to terminate. To have a hope of generating finite sequences, you'd need to weigh the probabilities heavily towards `A->v` and `B->eps` productions, or else just terminate artificially, saying that once you are `N` levels deep, `A` always goes to `v` and `B` to `eps`.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar has recursions. That is the reason, why it may continue long.

For example  can call again  recursivly. And so on and so on. Depending on the random number. In it will quite often happen that it runs until stack overflow :-)  The grammar is rather explosiv...

And if we show the states in a recursive decent way, we can just output the state in the nonterminal function. But I am not sure if that is what you want. I put the characters of the string in a vector. But, whatver container is ok.

The only terminals that you have are 'v', '+' and '-'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void PareY();
void PareA();
void PareB();
void PareE();

vector<vector<char>> strings{};;

int main() {
    strings.push_back({});
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    cout << "<E>::=(<Y>)" << endl;
    cout << "<Y>::=<A><B>" << endl;
    cout << "<A>::=ν|<Ε>" << endl;
    cout << "<Β>::=-<Υ>|+<Υ>|epsilon" << endl;
    cout << "\n\n---------------\n\nStart ";
    PareE();
    cout << "---------------\n\nStrings:\n\n" << endl;

    for (const auto& s : strings) {
        for (const char c : s) std::cout << c;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }



    return 0;
}

void PareE() {
    cout << " -> (E)";
    PareY();
}

void PareY() {
    cout << " -> (Y)";
    PareA();
    PareB();
}
void PareYPlus() {
    cout << " -> +(Y)";
    PareA();
    PareB();
}
void PareYMinus() {
    cout << " -> -(Y)";
    PareA();
    PareB();
}

void PareA() {
    cout << " -> (A)";
    if ((rand() % 2) == 0) {
        cout << " -> v";
        strings.back().push_back('v');
    }
    else {
        PareE();
    }
}
```

Potential output:

```
<E>::=(<Y>)
<Y>::=<A><B>
<A>::=ν|<Ε>
<Β>::=-<Υ>|+<Υ>|epsilon


---------------

Start  -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> (E) -> (Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> -(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> +(Y) -> (A) -> v -> (B) -> epsilon -> (B) -> epsilon---------------

Strings:


v-v-v+v
-v
-v-v+v+v
+v+v+v

+v-v

-v-v-v+v
-v-v
-v-v+v



+v-v-v+v
+v

-v-v-v
-v-v
-v-v+v+v-v+v+v-v
```